# Regex capturing: get only result from second group

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching, regular-language

I have a following string:

```
'pp_3', 365]
```

What comes after `pp_` may have different length. What comes after `,` and is before `]` is what I'd like to capture (and only it). Its length varies but it is always a number.

I've come up with [`(?<=pp_).*,(.*)(?=])`](https://regex101.com/r/vEe55a/1/). It gives `3', 365` as a full match and in group 1 there is what I want '365'. How do I get only `365` as a full match?

Please let me know if I am unable to explain my doubts. Thanks

Comment: why can't you not simply get between `,` and `]` ?  I would just use `indexOf` and `substring`

Comment: And why must the full match bet `365`? Why not simply access the first capturing group?

Comment: @ScaryWombat because the string is much larger than what I showed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
[^_]*_(\d*)'\s*,\s*(\-?\d+)\s*].
```

This regex captures 2 groups, that correspond to each of the numbers, the first after `pp_` and the second after `',` (which may be negative). If you don't want to capture the first one as a group, instead of `(\d*)`, just write `(?:\d*)`.

Comment: Thanks for this. Could you please rewrite your regex in that way it would capture only `365`'

Comment: Actually, it IS capturing only `365`. Have you tried? Give it a try and check if it works the way you want.

Comment: Yes, it does. Group 1. 8-11 `365` (taken from the link you sent).

Comment: My regex does what yours. I meant `365` as a full match (not in group).

Comment: OK, so is there a difference between the number that follows `pp_` and the number between `,` and `]`? Do any of them have some attributes, like maximum size or something like that? They are both numbers, so `\d` would match both. Is there a way to distinguish them? You can't hope to match only one number if there are more than one number to be catched.

Comment: I see. Thanks for this clarification. I can go with two groups: first capturing what comes after  `pp_` (it is always number), and second, i.e. characters after `', ` - here it is always number too, but it **may** be preceded with `-` (i.e. the number could be negative).

Comment: Edited my answer according to new constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Try this expression. The second group should be what you're after:

```
(?<='pp_)(\d*', )(\d*)]
```

Answer (score 0):

To match the digits only and if you want to make use of a positive lookbehind, you could make use of a quantifier in the lookbehind (which you can specify yourself) which is supported by Java

```
(?<=pp_[^,]{0,1000}, )\d+(?=])
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<=` Positive lookbehind, assert what is on the left is
- `pp_[^,]{0,1000}` Match `pp_`, match any char except `,` 0-1000 times
- `,`  Match a comma and space
- `)` Close lookbehind
- `\d+` Match 1+ digits
- `(?=])` Positive lookahead, assert what is on the right is `]`

In Java

```
String regex = "(?<=pp_[^,]{0,1000}, )\\d+(?=])";
```

[Java demo](https://ideone.com/BK1YXK)

You could also use a capturing group instead:

```
pp_[^,]*, (\d+)]
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LjCdJm/1)

Comment: It works but the result of the capturing is exactly the same as mine. Please see Daniel's answer - his solution does precisely what I wanted.